# How to send url and/or strings with spaces to a onclick function?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an innerHTML declared as follows:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<a href=\'#\' onclick=genGroups('+userid+',\''+coursename+'\','+url+')>'+coursename+'</a>';
```

I cant send any url and/or string variable(e.g coursename which has spaces in it) through the onclick. The error related to space(incase of string) and url(need a')' after argument) occurs. Any idea?

Comment: WHY. WHY ARE YOU DOING IT THIS WAY.

Comment: I need to generate a list of courses name onclicking them their corresponding groups will generate in other div. I am actually loading the first div with new divs(dynamically created from database call). Its a popup modal where there are three divs side by side. Any idea? Not interested in JQuery right now.

Comment: could you be more precise? you're probably aware that url's can't contain spaces(they become %20)? if that is what you meant? explain a bit more if i'm wrong

Comment: no I am getting 2 different errors for two different cases. one for string one for url.

Comment: ('+userid+',\''+coursename+'\','+url+') is it right? or **should it be:** ('+userid+'\','+coursename+'\','+url+')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the url should be quoted, too...

and the onclick="..." (with double quotes) would be nice

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<a href=\'#\' onclick="genGroups('+userid+',\''+coursename+'\',\''+url+'\')">'+coursename+'</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the functional method to add a click handler, rather than an inline handler:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = "<a href='#'>"+coursename+"</a>";

var a = newdiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
a.addEventListener('click', function() { genGroups(userid, coursename, url); });
```

Also, note the use of different forms of quotes, so you don't have to escape embedded quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do it with jQuery trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/WSzCh/ that is a lot cleaner and more flexible for your app.

```
var your_user_id = 1,
    your_course_name = 'whatever',
    your_url = 'nice url';

var genGroups = function(params){
    alert(params.userId);
    alert(params.coursename);
    alert(params.url);
};
// create a new empty link
var $myDiv = $('.myDiv'),
    $newLink = $('<a>');

// to store your meta properties as html data
$newLink.data({
    'userId':your_user_id,
    'coursename':your_course_name,
    'url':your_url
}).text(your_course_name);

// append the new link
$myDiv.append($newLink);


// bind the click event anywhere in your code
$myDiv .on( 'click','a', function() {
    var linkData = $(this).data();
    genGroups( linkData );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your quotes. Try this:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="genGroups('+userid+',\''+coursename+'\',\''+url+'\')">'+coursename+'</a>';
```

I suggest you using unobtrusive JS. You could store userid, coursename and url as data inside the `a`, and bind a click event. You could even fetch coursename from anchor.